# Gradle dependency cache may be corrupt Android studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

[image]    I am new to android studio ,when i open my project i got this error message,I attached error message with screen shot .

The Gradle file can't be syncronized,Once again i installed sdk but till now the problem can't be solved.

```
 please any one give the solution thanks in advance.

[Error message]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 In my case .gradle file is my problem so  i just followed the following below mentioned step:
Go to->C:\Users\mySystems\.gradle
  ->delete the .gradle file .
  ->Get the .gradle file from your friends or collligue and paste it
  ->Restart your android studio
  ->Works fine
```